# Filtering using collection_select params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, filter, parameters

I have simple form which allows users to filter search results according to `location_id` which is given in  `collection_select` form's field. I want to render narrowed results if  specific location is selected, and render all results if user selects default "Please select" field.

This code works good for separate locations, but not working if user selects "please select" field. `params[:location_id].blank?` in controller not working.

view

```
<%= form_tag @city %>
  <%= collection_select 'location_id', nil, @city.locations, :id, :address, prompt: true %>
  <%= submit_tag "sort", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-success travel-button", id: "hotels-radius-search-button" %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
if params[:location_id].blank?
  ...render all results...
else
  ..render specific results...
end
```

**Update**

Server's response

Parameters when default "Please select" option is selected -- not working

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_radius"=>"6", "location_id"=>[""], "_"=>"1365350127863", "id"=>"75"}
```

Parameters when user select any option in menu -- succesful

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_radius"=>"6", "location_id"=>["811"], "_"=>"1365350127865", "id"=>"75"}
```

or

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_radius"=>"6", "location_id"=>["808"], "_"=>"1365350127865", "id"=>"75"}
```

etc

Comment: What does your server say? Can you post the params it receives?

Comment: Hello Thomas! Thank you for th response, I ve included params to the question

Comment: The problem is, that you are posting `location_id` as an array somehow. Therefore `params[:location_id].blank?` is always `false`

Comment: Consider using `select_tag` for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This code works <%= select_tag(:location_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@city.locations, :id, :address, prompt: true), prompt: true) %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my answer, since comments cannot be accepted :-)

`collection_select` was used and was sending an `Array`.

Therefore usage of `select_tag` was suggested.